# Command Prompt Scripting

Tags: batch-file, automation, command-prompt

This is going to be hard to explain, I'll try my best.

I'm using a shell scripting (Test Executor) in command prompt to automate our regression testing.  However i'm stuck on one thing.

Basically I have to copy this dynamically created folder in a location into another folder after the automated script is done (in CMD via scripting)

```
:: create an achieve directory
@SET ACHIEVE_DIR=C:\Test Result\LOG_Files
mkdir "%ACHIEVE_DIR%"
xcopy /y /s /e "%TEST_SOURCE_DIR%"\*.* "%ACHIEVE_DIR%"
```

This will copy all the files in the TEST_SOURCE_DIR, but i only want this dynamically created folder which changes according to the date stamp (BUT this date stamp is calculated by second - so i can't use that as a variable).

For example: After i run a test it'll create a folder under lets say C:\temp\ another folder named "TEST RUN -  _2014-06-30 15_48_01_" 
So if go into C:\temp i'll find a folder named "TEST RUN -  _2014-06-30 15_48_01_" along with other folders. BUT i only want to copy this dynamic folder into Test Result\LOG_Files

What we are given is that the starting string will always be "TEST RUN -" but the ending string will interchange according to the time to the second (BUT we cannot go by that since it is the second of the starting test result).

I found out if i am in command prompt and i type in "cd TEST RU" and hit tab it'll finish it for me "cd TEST RUN -  _2014-06-30 15_48_01_" Is there a way to script this tab hit or something?

Thanks!

Comment: What has this to so with Selenium? What language are you using to script this? What is it you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: This is for my regression test. That's why i included selenium as a tag. This is the Command Prompt language ie. "mkdir" is sticky done on MS DOS etc.

Comment: If you insist on doing this with .bat scripting, this is going to be extremely difficult to do; see the `for /f` command to get you started. If you switch to a real scripting language, such as [tag:powershell] or something, then this should be very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work in a batch file to isolate the folder:
If there are a number of folders starting with `test run -` then tell us.

```
@echo off
SET "ACHIEVE_DIR=C:\Test Result\LOG_Files"
cd /d "c:\temp"
for /d %%a in ("test run -*") do xcopy "%%a\*.*" "%ACHIEVE_DIR%\" /s/h/e/k/f/c
```

This code looks for a test folder as discussed in the comments:

```
@echo off
SET "ACHIEVE_DIR=C:\Test Result\LOG_Files"
cd /d "c:\temp"
for /d %%a in ("test run -*") do (
    pushd "%%a"
       for /d /r %%b in ("test*") do (
          xcopy "%%b\*.*" "%ACHIEVE_DIR%\" /s/h/e/k/f/c
       )
    popd   
)
```

Comment: Quick question now that i got this copied but it copies everything in that folder but I only need whats in that folder \In\<dynamic folder name>\TEST\ 
so is there a way to change this part "%%a\*.*" into "%%a\In\*\TEST" a special note is that there is only one folder in "In" so is there a way to go into that location?

Comment: Change `"%%a\*.*"` to `"%%a\test\*.*"` if I understand you correctly.  If you also only want that single folder and no subdirectories then remove the `/s` and `/e` switches.

Comment: No no i mean - the foldering system dynamically creates this sub folders inside "test run -*" so it'll be `test run -*\In\***\TEST\` So what i need is to go inside `test run -*\In\***\TEST` and grab everything there .. folders and files but one thing to notice is that there are only one folder for every level after we are inside `test run -*` .. 

Note that each of these folders `In\***\TEST` only just have that one folder So essentially it should be like this:
`C:\Temp\TEST RUN - _2014-06-30 15_48_01_\In\19a2a552-88c3-4633-b7a8-8ced92819359\TEST\` 

Grab all the files from there

Comment: Is the ultimate folder called `TEST` ?

Comment: yes i want all the files from TEST folder. What your code does it copies everything from '\In\19a2a552-88c3-4633-b7a8-8ced92819359\TEST\' but if you could go in-dept a little more that'll be great!

Comment: :)  Notice that I fixed a typo above just now.  It didn't affect it when there was only one `test` folder in c:\temp but it should be more targeted now.

Comment: hey foxidrive .. i got another question fairly related to this, can you please have a look it shouldn't be long since you answered most of my question :   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24563087/batch-scripting-moving-files-with-timestamp

Comment: hey foxidrive.. The script got a little messed up that it started naming everything with date stamp and now i have over 1000 files with " - 09-07-2014 - 09-07-2014 - 09-07-2014 - 09-07-2014 - 21-07-2014 - 21-07-2014.jpg" at the end of it ... Is there a quick way to rename these by substringing this ending for every file on a given folder .. I am going to write this on command prompt

Comment: It's been a while but the scripts above don't rename the files at all.  Open a new question and describe the folder structure and filename format.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890079/command-prompt-scripting-to-rename-files
there we go .. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This batch file should do the job:

```
@echo off
rem Find the directory starting with "TEST RUN -" created last in C:\Temp.
set ACHIEVE_DIR=C:\Test Result\LOG_Files
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%D in ( `dir "C:\Temp\TEST RUN -*" /AD /B /O-D /TC` ) do (
   set TEST_SOURCE_DIR=%%D
   goto CopyDir
)
echo No directory starting with "TEST RUN -" found in C:\Temp.
pause
exit /b

:CopyDir
rem Copy all files and subdirectories from last test run to achieve
rem directory whereby xcopy automatically creates the achieve directory.
xcopy /E /I /Q /S /Y "%TEST_SOURCE_DIR%" "%ACHIEVE_DIR%"
set ACHIEVE_DIR=
set TEST_SOURCE_DIR=
```

Read the Microsoft pages about

- [dir](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/dir.mspx)
- [for](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx)
- [xcopy](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx)

for details about the used parameters of those 3 commands.

Or execute in a command prompt window the commands

- `dir /?`
- `for /?`
- `xcopy /?`

one after the other to get the shorter help for those 3 commands output in the window.