# Batch Scripting Moving files with timestamp

Tags: batch-file, scripting, move

So basically I have a file system C:\Test\BaseLine. Under BaseLine folder I have many folders, it could be one folder or 15 folders, in those folders are image files. I want to copy all the images from INSIDE those folder NOT including BaseLine folder into another location namely C:\Test\Achieve Images with Date stamp as 03-07-2014 at the end of each image.

For example i'll have folder system like this:
BaseLine - 1.jpg, 2.jpg 
->[Folder 123] - 3.jpg, 4.jpg
->[Folder 321] - 5.jpg, 6.jpg

At the end of my script i should have my C:\Test\Achieve images having these images like so:
Achieve Images - 3_03-07-2014.jpg, 4_03-07-2014.jpg, 5_03-07-2014.jpg, 6_03-07-2014.jpg

Notice how it does not include any of the BaseLine main folder images.

So far i have a script like this:

`cd /d "C:\Test\BaseLine\"
@SET DATE_FOLDER=%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~10,4% 
SET "ACHIEVE_DIR=C:\Test\Master Achieve"
for /d %%a in ("*") do xcopy "%%a\*.*" "%ACHIEVE_DIR%\" /s/h/e/k/f/c/y`
PS: This code was with the help of [user]foxidrive. Thanks again buddy for the other problem i had!!

This works but does not append the timestamp to the end of each image files
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it with `xcopy` but as you've outlined in the comments, this renames the files before copying.

The first four lines of this code will give you reliable YY DD MM YYYY HH Min Sec variables in XP Pro and higher.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

SET "DATE_FOLDER=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%"

cd /d "C:\Test\BaseLine\"
SET "ACHIEVE_DIR=C:\Test\Master Achieve" 
md "%ACHIEVE_DIR%" 2>nul

for /d %%a in (*) do (
for /r %%b in ("%%a\*.jpg") do ren "%%~b" "%%~nb - %DATE_FOLDER%%%~xb"
xcopy "%%a\*.jpg" "%ACHIEVE_DIR%\" /s/h/e/k/f/c/y
)
pause
```

**Edit** code to move all `*-tasty.jpg` files to the `%ACHIEVE_DIR%` and datestamp them, then remove the original containing folders under `C:\Test\BaseLine\` with all remaining files but leaving the files inside `C:\Test\BaseLine\` intact.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

SET "DATE_FOLDER=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%"

cd /d "C:\Test\BaseLine\"
SET "ACHIEVE_DIR=C:\Test\Master Achieve" 
md "%ACHIEVE_DIR%" 2>nul

for /d %%a in (*) do (
for /r %%b in ("%%a\*-tasty.jpg") do move "%%~b" "%ACHIEVE_DIR%\%%~nb - %DATE_FOLDER%%%~xb"
rd /s /q "%%a"
)
pause
```

Comment: What this does it creates another folder with the date stamp on the folder. This is not exactly what i want because essentially i want to look at "Master Achieve" folder with it all the images in one folder even from last year. Since i don't to overwrite any of the images that's why im putting a date stamp (it doesn't have to have a date stamp but it'll make it easier) - I DONT mind it overwriting on the same day though. But i don't want to have to look at many folders at the end of the year.

Comment: You need extra code to add a date stamp to the files.  A problem is that you can't just rename every file in the archive folder because you have said that there are more than one generation of files.  It can be done fairly easily if I can add a string to each renamed filename that is never in the filename, such as `--` or `==` perhaps before the date stamp.  This would allow the code to recognise which files are newly added and then to rename them.

Comment: Or i was thinking of renaming all the files before moving them. Ie. Rename them in the old folder and then move them to Master Achieve folder... This is what i have so far

'@SET DATE_FOLDER=%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%<br>
set folder=C:\Test\BaseLine\03-07-2014<br>
<br>
for /r "%folder%" %%n in (*) do call :renamefile "%%~nn" "%%~xn" "%%~dpn"<br>
goto :EOF<br>
<br>
:renamefile<br>
ren "%~3\%~1" "%~1_%DATE_FOLDER%%"'<br>
And then have the code above to move all the files
I am doing something wrong

Comment: For some reason it says The system cannot find the path specified. So strange. after this line `ren "C:\Test\BaseLine\03-07-2014\This is a test.jpg" "This is a test - 01-7/-.jpg"'  and the date format comes out wrong too

Comment: I found out it has to do with the 'SET DATE_FOLDER=%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~10,4%' if i change it to 'SET DATE_FOLDER="TEST"' works fine so some formating of that is wrong

Comment: See my edit again - it uses a robust date string method.

Comment: hey foxidrive ... back to this question - I noticed that this batch files renames everything in BaseLine folder. This is not what is suppose to happen. I only want folders within BaseLine folders. NOT the main folder itself -in this example i don't want Baseline folder's content to get renamed too only the folders within BaseLine/123/ directory to get renamed ... the coping part is right but the renaming seems to rename everything

Comment: I think I understand - try the edited code above.  If the batch file is run twice then the files will be renamed twice.

Comment: The code above didn't do anything but changes all the file names in BaseLine folder with the date stamp. Did not copy. 
Basically i want all the folders inside baseline to get the date stamp and copied to Master Achieve\ BUT NOT dot anything to the main folder in Baseline (ie. should not be renamed or copied)

Comment: The code renames `JPG` files that are `INSIDE folders` that are located in `C:\Test\BaseLine` so `C:\Test\BaseLine\fruit\apple.jpg` will be renamed and copied but `C:\Test\BaseLine\carrot.jpg` will not be renamed or copied.  All JPG files inside the `fruit` folder will be date-stamped and copied and they are all placed in the `C:\Test\Master Achieve` folder.  It seems that you may have leftover files in there from the previous runs which are confusing the matter. Copy and paste the code again - I eliminated a space and changed the filespec to *.jpg

Comment: You are RIGHT! It works! 
Just one more thing I Promise last one. Is it possible just to take the ending string of a jpg file
For example in C:\Test\BaseLine\fruit\
there are images called `apple - tasty.jpg` and `orange - tasty.jpg` and `pears - nottasty.jpg` and only date stamp and move the ones that end with `-tasty.jpg`? THANKS SO MUCH for the other help buddy

Comment: They aren't being moved - just copied.  Did you want just the `*-tasty.jpg` ones date stamped, copied and then deleted from the source folders?

Comment: well in the end i'll like the whole folder of fruits or any other folder within baseline to be deleted. So finally we'll have all the *-tasty.jpg images (under `baseline\*\`)renamed and moved and no folders will be under baseline

Comment: It does help to state the final task from the beginning - see the bottom batch code in my answer above.  Test it on some sample folders and files.

Comment: Sorry i was doing this manually didn't know if it's possible to code this. Is it possible to remove the -tasty part from it so at the end master achieve will have `apple - 20140722.jpg` `orange - 20140722.jpg` instead of apple-tasty- 20140722.jpg

Comment: It depends on what `-tasty` actually is and the real format of the filenames.

Comment: -tasty will always be .jpg and will always end with -tasty.jpg so we can go ahead and remove `-tasty.jpg` and replace it with the datestamp.jpg

Comment: I can't write code to change filenames without knowing anything about the real filenames.

Comment: oh sorry for privacy reason i cannot post them on the net. Lets say for example it's apple -tasty.jpg .. How would you go about with it. I know in RegEX you can group and save to memory to and replace with the group recall ... (.*)-tasty.jpg ---> [1]%datestamp%.jpg something like that

Comment: foxidrive i have a similar question if you want to help me out :) THANKS SO MUCH for your help!! 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897725/batch-scripting-moving-and-renaming-files

Comment: hey i have posted the file names on the other post. I tried using gbabu's rename method and having trouble with it can you please help me out?

Comment: is there a way to move them and then rename it? or is there a way to rename them and then move it? please help

Comment: I only saw names of fruit.

Answer (score 0):

This works -

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1 delims=." %%i in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime') do set ts=%%i
set dt=%ts:~6,2%-%ts:~4,2%-%ts:~0,4%

set workdir=D:\test\baseline\
set newdir=D:\test\Achieve\

cd %workdir%

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s *.jpg') do call :search "%%i"
goto :eof

:search
set filepath=%~f1
set dirpath=%~dp1
set filename=%~n1
set fileextn=%~x1
if "%dirpath%" EQU "%workdir%" goto :eof
copy /y "%filepath%" %newdir%\%filename%_%dt%%fileextn% >nul 2>&1

:eof
```

Test output -

```
D:\>dir "d:\test\baseline", "d:\test\baseline\Folder 123", "d:\test\baseline\Folder 321"
 Volume in drive D is New Volume
 Volume Serial Number is B04C-AB59

 Directory of d:\test\baseline

23/07/2014  21:24    <DIR>          .
23/07/2014  21:24    <DIR>          ..
23/07/2014  20:35                 2 1.jpg
23/07/2014  20:35                 2 2.jpg
23/07/2014  20:36    <DIR>          Folder 123
23/07/2014  20:37    <DIR>          Folder 321
               2 File(s)              4 bytes

 Directory of d:\test\baseline\Folder 123

23/07/2014  20:36    <DIR>          .
23/07/2014  20:36    <DIR>          ..
23/07/2014  20:36                 2 3.jpg
23/07/2014  20:36                 2 4.jpg
               2 File(s)              4 bytes

 Directory of d:\test\baseline\Folder 321

23/07/2014  20:37    <DIR>          .
23/07/2014  20:37    <DIR>          ..
23/07/2014  20:37                 2 5.jpg
23/07/2014  20:37                 2 6.jpg
               2 File(s)              4 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   7,037,329,408 bytes free

D:\>draft.bat

D:\test\baseline>cd\

D:\>dir d:\test\Achieve
 Volume in drive D is New Volume
 Volume Serial Number is B04C-AB59

 Directory of d:\test\Achieve

23/07/2014  21:24    <DIR>          .
23/07/2014  21:24    <DIR>          ..
23/07/2014  20:36                 2 3_23-07-2014.jpg
23/07/2014  20:36                 2 4_23-07-2014.jpg
23/07/2014  20:37                 2 5_23-07-2014.jpg
23/07/2014  20:37                 2 6_23-07-2014.jpg
               4 File(s)              8 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   7,037,329,408 bytes free
```

Cheers,
G

EDIT - This works based on your original question. I haven't seen the comments on the other answer yet. Let me know if you need changes.

Comment: The thing is Folder 123 will have files named as 3-tasty.jpg 3-not tasty.jpg 4-tasty.jpg 4-not tasty.jpg and same goes for Folder 321 5-tasty.jpg 5-not tasty.jpg 6-tasty.jpg 6-not tasty.jpg.. So in the end all the `-not tasty.jpg` will go into the main directory of baseline and all the `-tasty.jpg` will go into the achieve folder without the `-tasty.jpg` or `-not tasty.jpg` extension just the file name. So this batch script in the end will have ur other coding that you helped me solved with this - after all of this all the folders in baseline will be removed

Comment: Right now your achieve folder looks right. The end result should look like that. But your `D:\test\baseline:` should be 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, 4.jpg, 5.jpg and no other folders at the end of this batch run

Comment: so you dont want the date appended?

Comment: no no i do need it appeneded.. thats why i said your achieve folder is correct

Comment: And the date to be appended on non tasty files only?

Comment: No no -nontasty should not be date stampped but the 'non tasty' should be removed just like the other question you help me resolved. I am planning on putting both these solution in one batch file. ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897725/batch-scripting-moving-and-renaming-files

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your requirement yet. Can you provide the sample input folder/file structure and your expected output folder/file structure??

Answer (score 0):

BEFORE running draft.bat

```
D:\>dir "d:\test\baseline", "d:\test\baseline\Folder 123", "d:\test\baseline\Folder 321"
Volume in drive D is New Volume
Volume Serial Number is B04C-AB59
 Directory of d:\test\baseline

23/07/2014  21:24    <DIR>          .
23/07/2014  21:24    <DIR>          ..
23/07/2014  20:35                 2 1.jpg
23/07/2014  20:35                 2 2.jpg
23/07/2014  20:36    <DIR>          Folder 123
23/07/2014  20:37    <DIR>          Folder 321
               2 File(s)              4 bytes

 Directory of d:\test\baseline\Folder 123

23/07/2014  20:36    <DIR>          .
23/07/2014  20:36    <DIR>          ..
23/07/2014  20:36                 2 3-tasty.jpg
23/07/2014  20:36                 2 3-not tasty.jpg
23/07/2014  20:36                 2 4-tasty.jpg
23/07/2014  20:36                 2 4-not tasty.jpg
               2 File(s)              4 bytes

 Directory of d:\test\baseline\Folder 321

23/07/2014  20:37    <DIR>          .
23/07/2014  20:37    <DIR>          ..
23/07/2014  20:37                 2 5-tasty.jpg
23/07/2014  20:37                 2 5-not tasty.jpg
23/07/2014  20:37                 2 6-tasty.jpg
23/07/2014  20:37                 2 6-not tasty.jpg
               2 File(s)              4 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   7,037,329,408 bytes free

D:\>draft.bat
```

AFTER

```
D:\test\baseline>cd\

D:\>dir d:\test\Achieve
 Volume in drive D is New Volume
 Volume Serial Number is B04C-AB59

 Directory of d:\test\Achieve

23/07/2014  21:24    <DIR>          .
23/07/2014  21:24    <DIR>          ..
23/07/2014  20:36                 2 3_23-07-2014.jpg
23/07/2014  20:36                 2 4_23-07-2014.jpg
23/07/2014  20:37                 2 5_23-07-2014.jpg
23/07/2014  20:37                 2 6_23-07-2014.jpg
               4 File(s)              8 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   7,037,329,408 bytes free


 Directory of d:\test\baseline

23/07/2014  21:24    <DIR>          .
23/07/2014  21:24    <DIR>          ..
23/07/2014  20:35                 2 1.jpg
23/07/2014  20:35                 2 2.jpg
23/07/2014  20:35                 2 3.jpg
23/07/2014  20:35                 2 4.jpg
23/07/2014  20:35                 2 5.jpg
23/07/2014  20:35                 2 6.jpg
               2 File(s)              4 bytes
```

Notice how `baseline` does not have any more folders because they all got deleted after moving all of files 
`non-tasty` -> baseline without `non-tasty` extension
`tasty`     -> achieve without `tasty` but with date stamp

I hope you can understand now.
Thanks a lot