# Batch Scripting moving and renaming files

Tags: batch-file, scripting, command-prompt

I have another question, very similar to 
[Batch Scripting Moving files with timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24563087/batch-scripting-moving-files-with-timestamp/) But i'm having problems with it.

I have a file system C:\Test\Baseline - Under Baseline folder i have many folders ranging from 1 to 10+ these are all image files. I want to copy all the images inside those folders ending ONLY with `-not tasty.jpg` files into Baseline folder but removing the `-not tasty.jpg` part.

To put this into perspective here is an example:
`C:\Test\Baseline:`  apple.jpg, orange.jpg, watermellow.jpg, strawberry.jpg, eggs.jpg
`C:\Test\Baseline\07-14-14:` apples-tasty.jpg, apples-not tasty.jpg, fruits-tasty.jpg, fruits-not tasty.jpg
`C:\Test\Baseline\07-16-14:` cherry-tasty.jpg, cherry-not tasty.jpg, orange-tasty.jpg, orange-not tasty.jpg

So in the end when i run this batch script it should take the files from 07-14-14 apple-not tasty.jpg and fruits-not tasty.jpg rename them without -not tasty.jpg --> apple.jpg and fruits.jpg move/copy to it's parent directory `C:\Test\Baseline` and overwrite if necessary - Also take cherry-not tasty.jpg, orange-not tasty.jpg  --> cherry.jpg, orange.jpg move/copy to `C:\Test\Baseline`

So we are left with
`C:\Test\Baseline:`  apple.jpg, orange.jpg, watermellow.jpg, strawberry.jpg, eggs.jpg, fruits.jpg, cherry.jpg

I hope you can understand this. Any help will be grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will work for you -

```
@echo OFF

cd D:\test\baseline

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b "*-not tasty.*"') do copy /y "%%~fi" d:\test\baseline\* >nul 2>&1

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b "*-not tasty.*"') do CALL :rename "%%i" 
goto :EOF

:rename
set filename=%1
set newfilename=%filename:-not tasty=%
ren %filename% %newfilename% >nul 2>&1
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 del %newfilename% & ren %filename% %newfilename%

:EOF
```

Cheers,
G

Comment: hey gbabu, This works! but it also sends out this error message 
`Could Not Find D:\test\baseline\-not tasty   The syntax of the command is Incorrect` BUT it does work. is there a small fix to this/? THANKS

Comment: Ahh. Forgot to out a line break before "goto :EOF", just after the 2nd for loop. It should be ok now.

Comment: GREATT!! IT works! Thanks @gbabu! Can you also help me with this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24563087/batch-scripting-moving-files-with-timestamp/24575806?noredirect=1#comment38674569_24575806 It's similar most is done but i just need to remove the -tasty and also move the file....