# Command Prompt Scripting to rename files

Tags: scripting, command-prompt

I got some help scripting a batch script to date stamp image files from foxidrive. However, i messed up on the directory and it date stamped everything in that folder. So right now i have 1000+ images (.jpg) files with this string on the end of each file name " - 09-07-2014 - 09-07-2014 - 09-07-2014 - 09-07-2014 - 21-07-2014 - 21-07-2014.jpg".

Is there a way to rename these by removing the string above from these file names on every .jpg file on a given folder? I am planning to write this on command prompt

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch this in the folder and then examine `renfiles.bat` to see if the rename commands look right, before removing the `.txt` and running it.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.jpg) do (
echo "%%a"|repl "^.(.*) - 09-07-2014 - 09-07-2014 - 09-07-2014 - 09-07-2014 - 21-07-2014 - 21-07-2014.*" "ren $& \q$1%%~xa\q" ax >> renfiles.bat.txt
)
```

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` (by dbenham) - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

Comment: It kinda worked but the only problems is that these filenames have & in them. So it kept throwing out 'xxx' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch files ... ie. "abc&de - 09-07-2014 - 09-07-2014 - 09-07-2014 - 09-07-2014 - 21-07-2014 - 21-07-2014.jpg"

Comment: Okay i run it ... it creates an empty renfiles.bat.txt but no errors this time

Comment: It would seem that the filenames don't have that exact string in them.  You did download repl.bat didn't you?

Comment: Yes i did .. Here is an example of a filename YXZ Court Doc - 09-07-2014 - 09-07-2014 - 09-07-2014 - 09-07-2014 - 21-07-2014 - 21-07-2014.jpg  which should be YXZ Court Doc.jpg

Comment: I edited the code to remove extra quotes - but it does list the filename with the ren command in the output file.  It had a flaw where it would only list the last picture too - fixed that also.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

set workdir=d:\test

cd %workdir%

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s *.jpg') do call :search "%%i"
goto :eof

:search

set filename=%~n1
set fileextn=%~x1

set newfilename=%filename: - 09-07-2014 - 09-07-2014 - 09-07-2014 - 09-07-2014 - 21-07-2014 - 21-07-2014=%

ren "%filename%%fileextn%" "%newfilename%%fileextn%" >nul 2>&1


:eof
```

Sample -

```
D:\>dir d:\test
 Volume in drive D is New Volume
 Volume Serial Number is B04C-AB59

 Directory of d:\test

24/07/2014  19:16    <DIR>          .
24/07/2014  19:16    <DIR>          ..
24/07/2014  19:09                 2 ABC Court Doc - 09-07-2014 - 09-07-2014 - 09-07-2014 - 09-07-2014 - 21-07-2014 - 21-07-2014.jpg
24/07/2014  19:09                 2 YXZ Court Doc - 09-07-2014 - 09-07-2014 - 09-07-2014 - 09-07-2014 - 21-07-2014 - 21-07-2014.jpg
           2 File(s)              4 bytes
           2 Dir(s)   7,037,292,544 bytes free

D:\>draft.bat

D:\test>dir d:\test
 Volume in drive D is New Volume
 Volume Serial Number is B04C-AB59

 Directory of d:\test

24/07/2014  19:16    <DIR>          .
24/07/2014  19:16    <DIR>          ..
24/07/2014  19:09                 2 ABC Court Doc.jpg
24/07/2014  19:09                 2 YXZ Court Doc.jpg
           2 File(s)              4 bytes
           2 Dir(s)   7,037,292,544 bytes free
```

Cheers, G